# Validate input field with ACF field

Tags: php, forms, validation, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a site right now and my client wants to unlock a page by pasting a few hundred emails into a field and the unlock happens if any of those emails was used in the first field and a fixed password in the second one. You can see that in the screen below:

https://prnt.sc/ujwl80

This is my template:

```
https://pastebin.com/Ftvw7bdk
```

This is the part of the code that is causing me trouble:

https://prnt.sc/ujwmo1

```
$user == "{$emails}"
```

I need those entries to be saved as a new entry or "row" just like it looks like in that email and later when they submit and any of those emails match together with the password then it should open up.

So my questions is how to make such an array and make it check for content and unlock if it finds any matches. Any of these emails:

https://prnt.sc/ujwnmv

If I just enter 1 email in here then it works because its just taking the input from that field. If I use more emails then I need to paste them all into the field in order to unlock the page.

Any Ideas on how to pull that off?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explode the string into an array. To do so, use the explode() PHP function while passing both the delimiter to explode on, in this case, it will probably be a new line and the string itself.

```
$email_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $emails);
```

Note that PHP_EOL is a constant set within the PHP ini, so it should work out the box most times but if your ACF field has some random line endings then you might get some odd results. Just explore with PHP_EOL or "\n" until you get the desired result.

Once you have this in an array it should be simple to loop through as normal.

Thanks,
T

Comment: Hi T, thanks for the quick reply. Can I kindly ask for an example of how you would do it? I'm still not sure how to pull it off. 

Thanks in advance.